# Google play game services unity player rank

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, leaderboard

I implemented in my Unity project the google play game services. The leaderboard is showing and working just fine, but I want to get the rank of the player.

```
public static void ShowLeaderboardsUI()
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(
        myString,
        LeaderboardStart.PlayerCentered,
        100,
        LeaderboardCollection.Public,
        LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime,
        (data) =>
        {
            RankTxt.text = data.PlayerScore.rank.ToString() + "///" + data.PlayerScore.leaderboardID.ToString() + "///" + data.PlayerScore.userID.ToString() + "///" + data.PlayerScore.value.ToString() + "///" + data.Scores.Rank.ToString();
            RankTxt.text = data.PlayerScore.rank.ToString() + "///" + data.PlayerScore.leaderboardID.ToString() + "///" + data.PlayerScore.userID.ToString() + "///" + data.PlayerScore.value.ToString() + "///" + data.Scores.Rank.ToString();
        });
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI(myString);
}
```

But RankTxt is always empty, any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

You did your code properly, however you libgpg.so file is probably old. Try deleting Plugins/Android/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgpg.so and Plugins/Android/libs/x86/libgpg.so. Then reimport those files from the latest plugin.